# Conditional test skip in protractor using jasmine on runtime

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

My scenario is that one spec.js file contains many test cases let say 10 test case in smoke.js file.Excel sheet contains test data like
Excel sheet name: smoke

Testcase--Execute

Test1      --     Yes

Test2     --       No

I read data from Excel and based on "Execute" column value need to run test.
I need to run "Test1" from smoke.js only and skip "Test2" .

I read many posts unfortunately i didn't get solution for my problem.

Comment: Do you want to run "it" or "Describe" blocks conditionally in an spec file ?

Comment: I want to run "it" block conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent tests from happening with conditionals. There might be a better way to do this. Below is an example of how to do this:

```
var tests = {
  'spec1': {
    'test1': 'Y',
    'test2': 'N'
  }
};


var spec1 = tests.spec1;
describe('spec1', () => {
  if (spec1.test1 == 'Y') {

    it('test1', () => {
      console.log('test1 executed');
    });
  } else {
    console.log('test1 not executed');
  }

  if (spec1.test2 == 'Y') {
    it('test2', () => {
      console.log('test2 executed');
    });
  } else {
    console.log('test2 not executed');
  }
});
```

In the example below I'm using `var tests` but in the above scenario, you could generate a JavaScript file from your spreadsheet prior to running the Protractor tests then require that file in your spec.

Comment: specs in protractor jasmine are always executed disregard to putting them in if condition. if someone want to follow solution above they must put if condition inside spec that means it so sth like 

it('my spec', () => {
  if(YOUR CONDITION) {
   YOUR CODE
  }
});

Comment: The person asked if they could do it. My answer was yes and here is how you would go about doing it. It did not ask if it is a good idea. The downvote + your comment implies that my answer is wrong. Please feel free to create your own answer.

Comment: My intention over here is to highlight that solution did not work. I wanted to save future debugger effort. Like i said as part of my reply we can still put IF condition inside IT block but that's not way this problem has to be solved.
I tried various other way nothing worked.
So i don't have a real answer either.

Comment: I wrote this answer 4 years ago when I was working on Protractor. It might have worked back then and I am not sure what Jasmine did since version 2.6.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and mention Jasmine version number that will help me reverting my vote?